# react-native run-android Cannot read packageName

Tags: react-native

I using this code react-native run-android It gives this error

Cannot read packageName from D:\projects\test3\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

when I update my Gradle version to 2.2

[image]

this is my manifest file code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test3">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <service android:name=".HeadlessTaskService"
                 android:enabled="true" />
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.make sure your device is connected and you had enabled debugging mode in it.

2.set paths for android_home,tools and platform_tools

3.then on console run,

```
 adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

this command runs properly on android devices having version greater than 4.4

4.then try

```
  react-native run-android
```